# VBA- Getting HREF from TR sublists

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to pull all of the individual cells and data from the tables on this site: *https://www.world-airport-codes.com/*, and specifically the rows on the subpage here *https://www.world-airport-codes.com/alphabetical/airport-code/a.html?page=1* by looping through the different pages and subpages.

The issue is that while this worked just fine for the text, I can't get the reference links contained in the first cell (I will need to loop through all those pages eventually as well).

The structure of the page element is as follows

> Blockquote

```
<tbody>
<tr class="light-row">
<th>

                   <a> href="/french-polynesia/anaa-226.html">Anaa</a>
```

```
                        <td>
                            <span class="hide-for-large mini-header">Type: </span>
                            Medium airport                            </td>

                                                        <td style="padding: 0;"></td>
                        
                                                        <td><span class="hide-for-large mini-header">Country: </span>French Polynesia</td>
                        
                                                        <td><span class="hide-for-large mini-header">IATA: </span>AAA</td>
                        
                                                        <td><span class="hide-for-large mini-header">ICAO: </span>NTGA</td>
```

> Blockquote

My code is as follows (this is simplified to cut out all the page and subpage loops)

```
Sub ListVideosOnPage(VidCatName As String, VidCatURL As String)

Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim VidRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim VidRows As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection


Dim TableSection As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim TableRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim TableCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim VidLink As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim TableLink As MSHTML.IHTMLElement


XMLReq.Open "Get", VidCatURL, False
XMLReq.send

If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
    MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & "-" & XMLReq.statusText
    Exit Sub
End If

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
Set XMLReq = Nothing

Set VidRows = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("stack2")


For Each VidRow In VidRows
    'Set VidLink = VidRow.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
    'Debug.Print VidLink.tagName, VidLink.innerText, VidLink.getAttribute("href")
    
    
    For Each TableRow In VidRow.Children
    'Set VidLink = TableRow.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
    'Debug.Print TableRow.tagName, TableRow.innerText, TableRow.getAttribute("href")

        
        
       
        
        For Each TableCell In TableRow.Children
        'Set VidLink = TableCell.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
        'Debug.Print TableCell.tagName, TableCell.innerText, TableCell.getAttribute("href")
        
            For Each TableLink In TableCell.Children
            Set VidLink = TableLink.getElementsByTagName("th")(0)
            Debug.Print TableLink.tagName, TableLink.innerText, TableLink.getAttribute("href")
        
        
           Next TableLink
        
        Next TableCell
        
        
     Next TableRow
    
    
Next VidRow
```

End Sub

I left in the commented out sections in the "for each" sections just to show what my thinking was.

The two issues I have are it either returns a NULL for the href (as in this case), OR, if I change the debug.print to **VidLink** instead of TableLink I get a **Runtime Error 91 Object Variable** (I've tried setting this multiple ways).

Some of the other things I have tried include changing the Variables to collections and setting up more variables to loop through the  rows specifically, as well as doing direct .href value references too. This isn't a  class so I don't know why it isn't getting the attribute.

I've spent an absurd amount of time going around in circles on this and I've really lost the thread on this. My biggest frustration is that I don't understand what is wrong with my thinking on this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please provide test values for VidCatName and  VidCatURL  and indicate one of the expected return urls

Answer (score 0):

The website I suspect does not permit scraping. I notice it fingerprints superficially your request. It is sufficient, though I don't condone this, to randomize what is passed in the `User-Agent` header.

Then you need to do a case sensitive test on whether the current tag is a TH when looping over the table from row 2 onwards. If it is a `TH` then you can grab the child `a` tag, first checking there is one, and print the `href` attribute.

There is only a single table so you can just grab that with querySelector. Also, use exact typing where possible.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ListVideosOnPage()
    Dim xmlReq As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    Set xmlReq = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60: Set htmlDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    xmlReq.Open "Get", "https://www.world-airport-codes.com/alphabetical/airport-code/a.html?page=1", False
    xmlReq.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", CStr(Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 1000000000))
    xmlReq.send

    If xmlReq.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & xmlReq.Status & "-" & xmlReq.statusText
        Exit Sub
    End If

    htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = xmlReq.responseText
    
    Dim vidTable As MSHTML.HTMLTable, vidRow As MSHTML.HTMLTableRow
    Dim vidCell As MSHTML.HTMLTableCell, i As Long

    Set vidTable = htmlDoc.querySelector(".stack2") 'Single table
    
    For i = 1 To vidTable.Rows.Length - 1        'loop rows of table
        Set vidRow = vidTable.Rows(i)
        
        For Each vidCell In vidRow.Children
            If vidCell.tagName = "TH" And vidCell.Children.Length > 0 Then Debug.Print vidCell.Children(0).href 'Test if header tag. Case sensitive.
            Debug.Print vidCell.innerText
        Next vidCell
        
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked and got me moving in the right direction. I really, really appreciate it.